# How to access MongoDb collections dynamically through nodejs in a Mern Project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mern

I am developing a **Recipe Website** using **Mern Stack**. I have my data in MongoDb atlas cloud.

My Database structure is like==>

```
 Recipe
        Dessert
        Breakfast
        Lunch
        QuickRecipes
```

Here, Recipe is the database and **Dessert, breakfast, Lunch and QuickRecipes** are collection. This collections contains several documents inside it. Now, I have to access this data. I have made a Mongoose model for it, as below and accessed the data by using this model from **controllers.**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const dessertSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    level_0:{type:Number,default:0},
    index:Number,
    RecipeId:{type:Number,default:0},
    Name:String,
    AuthorId:Number,
    AuthorName:String,
    CookTime:String,
    PrepTime:String,
    TotalTime:String,
    DatePublished:{type:Date,default:new Date()},
    Description:String,
    Images:[String],
    RecipeCategory:String,
    Keywords:[String],
    RecipeIngredientQuantities:[String],
    RecipeIngredientParts:[String],
    AggregatedRating:{type:Number,default:0},
    ReviewCount:{type:Number,default:0},
    Calories:Number,
    FatContent:Number,
    SaturatedFatContent:Number,
    CholesterolContent:Number,
    SodiumContent:Number,
    CarbohydrateContent:Number,
    FiberContent:Number,
    SugarContent:Number,
    ProteinContent:Number,
    RecipeServings:Number,
    RecipeYield:Number,
    RecipeInstructions:[String]

    
});

export default mongoose.model('Dessert', dessertSchema);
```

Through the above Schema, I am able to access the data, But, now the problem is I have **many categories Collection**. Like, I have nearly 90 collections for categories. Making the Schema for 90 collections will make the code more repeated. **Also, the data type for each Collection is same**. So, Is there any way through which I can just make one Schema and **dynamically** access the data through controllers.

*Note: I will get the category name through frontend, Like Frontend will send me 'Dessert', so I Have to go to Dessert collection and return all documents.*

**Thank you in Advance.**

Comment: Rather than having so many collections, might it make everything easier to add a `category` field to the collection schema?